# Why the OSGI element cannot be recognized by the STS?

Tags: spring-tool-suite

The xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:osgi="http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi/spring-osgi.xsd">

    <bean id="demoBean"
          class="org.spring.demo.DemoBean">
    </bean>

    <osgi:service ref="demoBean" interface="org.spring.demo.DemoInterface"></osgi:service>

</beans>
```

The SpringExplorer lists the "demoBean" node, but doesn't list the element of "osgi:service".
Other spring eclipse plugin should be installed?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this looks a little bit like a bug that I recently fixed in STS:
https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-3674

So it may be worth trying updating your STS from nightly update site.

It could also be

- another bug in STS causing it to miss beans that actually exist
- a problem with the bean definition or schema causing the bean not to be properly defined.

You can try to distinguish between these two cases by making sure the beans you think should exist actually do exist at runtime when the application context is instantiated.

If the bean in fact exist and doesn't show up in STS model, then I'd consider that a bug in STS and you should consider filing a bug report. Otherwise it is another problem.

Comment: If you decide to file a bug report, the correct bug tracker for STS is not the one the linked bug is in, but this one: https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS